# any java dynamic feature same with .net dynamic keyword

Tags: dynamic

in .NET world, a method as below:

```
public static int getLength(dynamic unknown){
return unknown.getLength();
}
```

dynamice is a keyword in C#/.Net,  unknown is a dynamic, unknown.getLength(); doestn't cause build error/fail. 
if a variable has a method getLength() and return int.  the method can pass. the real type of unknown is not important.

I want to know any feature of dynamic type or calling in Java same with .NET dynamic.

thanks very much.